# intel xdk - how to save project to the cloud?

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

As my understanding goes, it is possible to save our ongoing projects into the cloud services provided by intel. But I'm not being able to do so.

What would the step-by-step procedure be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an account https://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/csd/cloud-services-dashboard-login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcsd%2fcontrolpanel.aspx%3f
For more info see www.html5dev-software.intel.com/...DOC=ARTICLE_APPDEVCENTER